# What exactly is namasmarana

Tags: gods, philosophy, karma, japa

What exactly is namasmarana?

1. In namasmarana is there any importance to just chant a name of god (mind may or may not be on it) ?
2. If namasmarana is chanting the name with remembering god in mind- then - how exactly to remember god while chanting his name? God is nirakar - hence i can not have his photo in mymind. Because that will be the smaran of fake photograph.

So how exactly to do smaran of god.

Eg. If a person is doing namasmaran for 5000 times, then he will definitely require around 2 hours.

In these 2 hours of period is it just important to take his name with mouth or what is exact procedure to remember him?

Comment: You could say it as it is. But concentrating on God's form is better. First of all his form is **not fake**. Secondly Krsna himself recommends concentration on his form in the Bhagavat Gita. Chanting his name is very good but chanting it thinking about him is a lot more powerful.

Comment: I think you cleared one daubt , Chanting his name is very good (mind may or may not be on it)..  Second one still exists, what to think about him? give me example.. what commentry should one play in his mind while chanting holy name for 2 hours?

Comment: It doesnt matter, the purpose of Namasmarana is to take attention of Mind away from Worldly objects and put focus on One Object (doesnt matter whether it is fake or real) it matters about your FAITH. If you have the conviction that God is always within you, then that is Namasmarana. If you repeat the name constantly then it is Namasmarana. Smarana means remembrance. Nama smarana means remembrance of the name of God. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

The highest ideal of Namasmarana might well be the popular phrase from the scriptures : 
*Sarvadaa Sarvakaleshu Sarvatra Harichintanam*

**The Mind's involvement :** 
In the Gita, Arjuna asks Krishna, about the wavering of the mind. Krishna says that repeated practice (Abhyasa) and dispassion (Vairagya) are the tools by which to conquer it.

http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/living/living_22.html

In the beginning, Namasmarana may be mechanical, but in due course, mind is reined in. Recognizing this difficulty, the Sandilya Upanishad, mentions three levels of Japa, Vaikhari (loud), Upamsu (whisper) and Manasa (mental).

http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1025

**Significance of the form** : Focus on a single name and a single form is recommended for gradually increasing the levels of contemplation. The gross appearance of the picture itself is not referred to as significant, it could be anything, don't worry if it is a painting by Ravi Varma or from a local press. What is more important that it's continued rememberance. For a sincere aspirant, God will manifest in the form that the devotee prays. Well, in the case of Prahlada, he even appeared in a form first of its kind, in which Prahlada would have never imagined!

[Sri Ramakrishna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramakrishna) is the best example of this, his chosen form was the Bhavadharini in the temple built by Rani Rasamoni in Dakshineswar, but that one form was enough him for him, so much so that, at one point he could feel the breath of the Goddess! It must be said, he also later checked out Christianity and had a vision of Christ, similarly with Islam. During one phase he worshipped Hanuman intensely and had experiences related to that one-pointed worship.

Similar is the experience of Meera, Andal or Arunagiranathar.

Counting the number of times or hours, is considered common in the initial stages of Namasmarana, and one can use a Japa Mala if you wish. But, Bhava or feeling is the most important, and over time, count and duration will drop on their own account, like the modules of a rocket that fall off to spur the rocket ahead.

**Visualization :** One could pick any favorite form or any favorite deity (and preferably, stick to it all through, everyday). One can visualize the form from the feet to the head. One can remember the Lord's Leelas. If you are chanting a mantra, one can dwell on the meaning of the mantra.  In the [Gita, Chapter 10](http://asitis.com/10/), Krishna says :

> The thoughts of My pure devotees dwell in Me, their lives are
>   surrendered to Me, and they derive great satisfaction and bliss
>   enlightening one another and conversing about Me.

The visualization is a powerful one. Consider these levels for evolution, in increasing order of intensity and importance :

The picture that we see outside is, **Bahya Chitram**, the picture without.

The picture that we see within is, **Bhava Chitram**, the picture within, reminiscing the Lord's attributes and leelas.

The picture that we internalize and experience within, without and everywhere in everyone , is, **Sakshatkara Chitram**, the transcendental form or the all-pervasive form.

The above gradation is explained by Sathya Sai Baba in one of his discourses. (p.s.Can't place the reference now, will have to add later.

Comment: is mechanical chanting is namaparadh? (not exactly i mean mechanical chant , ofcourse , chanting with inner faith , but due to wordly things in front of eyes, mind may be any where else , but mouth continues chanting)